# Slice dataframe by range starting at the end of the frame

Tags: python, dataframe, indexing, slice

I have a dataframe like

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'one':[1,2,3,4,5],'two':['one','two','three','four','five']})

    c1    c2
0    1    one
1    2    two
2    3  three
3    4   four
4    5   five
```

which I would like to slice by a range starting at the last row, e.g index 1 to 3 but in a way that I could use it like I would use

```
.tail(-4:-1)
```

that would give me

```
    c1    c2
1    2    two
2    3  three
3    4   four
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's what `.loc` and `.iloc` are for. Read more [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-use-loc-and-iloc-for-selecting-data-in-pandas-bd09cb4c3d79)

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'c1':[1,2,3,4,5],'c2':['one','two','three','four','five']})

print(df.iloc[-4:-1])
```

**Output:**

```
print(df.iloc[-4:-1])
   c1     c2
1   2    two
2   3  three
3   4   four
```